# Porting from MSVC2015 Update 2 to GCC 5.3 - SFINAE Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14, porting, gcc5

I'm currently porting my library, but my dark template magic won't get compiled with GCC 5.3

### This fragment works as expected when compiled with MSVC2015 Update 2

```
template<typename vreal = 
    std::enable_if<std::is_vreal<vreal>::value, 
                   floatType>::type>
inline vreal foo(vreal bar)
{
    return bar;  
}

template<typename vreal = 
    std::enable_if<std::is_vreal<vreal>::value, 
                   floatType>::type>
struct bar { vreal i; };
```

GCC complains about "vreal was not defined in current scope (WTF?)"

### What I've tried so far:

Rewrite the upper template fragment to

```
template<typename vreal, 
         typename enable = typename std::enable_if<std::is_vreal<vreal>::value != 0>::type>
```

But this doesn't work either. It breaks much much later in the code and I assume that it's due the introduction of the additional template param.

Also, I don't understand why I had to introduce the comparison with 0. Without it gcc complained about missing 'type' on enabled_if.

So, the main question is: how to get the same SFINAE logic (compile ONLY if the argument is vreal) WITHOUT additional arguments.

I could rewrite that to return type SFINAE - but that would be a lot of work which I'd like to avoid (differentiating between functions, classes, structs, typedefs / usings...) even though it's wrapped in a macro.

```
 template<typename vreal>
 typename std::enable_if<is_vreal<vreal>, vreal>::type inline vreal .....
```

Comment: gcc has every right to complain about `vreal` not being defined here. Furthermore, I am unable to find `std::is_vreal` anywhere in my copy of the C++ standard. I have some bad news for you: you've been embraced-and-extended, by Microsoft.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik std::is_vreal was my specialization for std::is_floating_point which I rewrote but forgot to remove from std. Furthermore, I remember REsharper complaining about undefined vreal, too. Is it that my implementation was wrong from the beginning and MSVC just compiled it?

Comment: never add your own things into the standard namespace.  It is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid C++:

```
template<typename vreal = 
  std::enable_if<std::is_vreal<vreal>::value, 
               floatType>::type>
inline vreal foo(vreal bar)
{
  return bar;  
}
```

for many reasons.  It uses a symbol in `std` that isn't in `std` (`is_vreal`), which means your program is ill-formed.  It uses a token `floatType` that is not defined (you did post a [MCVE] right?).  It uses `vreal` before it is in scope, in the definition of `vreal`.

I have no idea what it is supposed to mean, other than your seeming belief that it does SFINAE magic: it states that if `vreal` passes the `is_vreal` test, it should be the type `floatType` by default.  But in order to reach this point, you had to have the type `vreal` already, so the default type doesn't seem to matter.

Also, `::type` is not a type in a dependent context:, so `std::enable_if<std::is_vreal<vreal>::value,  floatType>::type` should complain that you are using a non-type named `::type` in a context where a type is expected.  You need to do `typenam estd::enable_if<std::is_vreal<vreal>::value, floatType>::type`.

You seem to also state that you are using macros to generate code.  That was a poor decision.

As far as I can tell, simply removing the `enable_if` clause completely will solve your problem for most cases.

The exception is for functions, because there can be overloads, you can introduce a SFINAE helper.

Ditch the macro completely.  Class and function templates work significantly differently anyhow.

For classes/structs:

```
template<class vreal>
struct bar { vreal i; };
```

because there really isn't another alternative -- there isn't the concept of overloading with structures/classes like there is with functions.

For functions, we want a SFINAE test so we can overload:

```
template<class T, class R=T>
using vreal_test = typename
  std::enable_if<std::is_vreal<T>::value, R>::type

template<class vreal>
inline vreal_test<vreal> foo(vreal bar)
{
  return bar;  
}
```

if the function returns a differnet type, do

```
template<class vreal>
inline vreal_test<vreal,void> foo2(vreal bar)
{
  return;
}
```

You can do this as you sweep to remove your macro.

Comment: Thank you. I got it working yesterday. Concerning the is_vreal and floatType: is_vreal is my defintion - previously a  'is_floating_point' specialization. I forgot to remove it from std. and floatType is a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 0):

For your top function, you can have this:

```
template<typename vreal>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_vreal<vreal>::value, floatType>::type foo(vreal bar)
{
    return bar;
}
```

Your structure should also be redefined. The solution below can't get away from using the secondary parameter Enable here, with a partial specialization:

```
template<typename vreal, typename Enable = void>
struct bar;

template<typename vreal>
struct bar<vreal, typename std::enable_if<std::is_vreal<vreal>::value, void>::type>
{ vreal i; };
```

(Assuming floatType and std::is_vreal are appropriately defined somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

I would separate SFINAE from template parameters that you actually use. A non type additional parameter is ideal for this case.

For the struct, I would use `enable_if` and specialize a base class.

It would look like this:

```
template<typename vreal, typename std::enable_if<std::is_vreal<vreal>::value, int>::type = 0>
vreal foo(vreal bar) { 
    return bar;
}

template<typename vreal, typename = void>
struct barBase; // optionally add a static_assert for better messages

template<typename vreal>
struct barBase<vreal, typename std::enable_if<std::is_vreal<vreal>::value>::type> {
    vreal i;
};

template<typename vreal>
using bar = barBase<vreal>;
```

I don't think `std::is_vreal` exists. If it does, surely not in GCC. Don't inject things in the std namespace, compilers are free to refuse it.